# Merging two WordPress Post/Comments tables in MySQL phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I know the "merge tables" question has already been asked in a variety of ways, but I can't seem to find an answer to my specific question.

Here's my deal: I've been designing a WordPress site for an organization for four weeks. When I began designing I took an export of the database and imported into my local development site. In the meantime, this organization has naturally continued to post things and receive/approve comments on their live site. On the local side, I have also created posts, edited pages, changed widgets, etc during development. So now that we're ready to launch the new site, I need to figure out how to merge these last four weeks of database changes from both the live site and the local site without losing anything on either side. How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there have been inserts to both databases, then unfortunately there isn't a good way to merge. If your database contains the latest edits for the Post IDs that are shared then you can export them to XML and then import them into the other site.

This is done with the [WordPress Importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/) plugin which can also be installed by visiting `/wp-admin/import.php`, the export can be done on `/wp-admin/export.php`. You can also remove any conflicts from the XML file manually, but make sure that you keep it well-formed.